# Symfony 2 - Bidirectionnal translation

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization, locale, translation

I have to translate a website where the page content can be writen in English or in French. 
So I made two files in my translations repository:

- message.en.yml (to translate **french to english** when the locale is **en_us or en_gb**)
- message.fr.yml (to translate **english to french** when the locale is **fr**)

To explain my issue I will take an exemple, the pair of word `Hardware | Matériel`.
When the page is viewed with **fr** locale `Hardware` need to be translated by `Matériel`.
So I put : `Hardware: Matériel` in my `message.fr.yml`.
When the page is viewed with **en_us or en_gb** locale `Matériel` need to be translated by `Hardware`.
So I put : `Matériel: Hardware` in my `message.en.yml`.
At this point the translation behaviour is:
When the page is viewed with the fr locale `Hardware` is correctly translated.
When the page is viewed with the en_gb locale `Hardware` is correctly not translated.
When the page is viewed with the en_us locale `Hardware` is incorrectly translated by `Matériel`.
To add to the fun, if I clear the Symfony cache, the behaviour change, sometimes everything get translated by `Matériel`, sometimes nothing does...
A week ago I only needed to translate French to English and it worked perfectly by just using the message.en.yml file, maybe there is something to do that I didn't noticed when you use several files.
**Can someone explain me how to handle this two way translation?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I understood what I was doing wrong.
For this kind of situation you have to:

- Put : `Hardware: Matériel` in my message.fr.yml. (if fr locale translate `Hardware`by `Matériel`)
- Put : `Matériel: Hardware` in my message.en.yml. (if en locale translate `Matériel`by `Hardware`)
- Put : `Hardware: Hardware` in my message.en.yml. (if en locale **don't translate** `Hardware`)

I think all of this happend because of the translation fallback, I ask for the translation of `Hardware`so symfony look for one in message.en.yml.first (because the locale is en), if it doens't find any, it looks for it in message.fr.yml, here it found `Hardware: Matériel`so it use it.
I still don't get why sometime, depending on the cache, the translation worked fine on en_gb locale...

Answer (score 1):

Use variables.

I'm using translation like this:

messages.en.yml

```
string.hardware: Hardware
```

messages.fr.yml

```
string.hardware: Matériel
```

In twig:

```
{{ "string.hardware"|trans }}
```

Using with dynamic variables:

```
string.hardware: %variable% Hardware
```

Usage in twig:

```
{{ "string.hardware"|trans({"%variable%": your_variable_or_string}) }}
```

Comment: I don't think I can do this because the things I translate are often variables, for exemple there is a place where I loop over objects properties and I translate every property of the object.

Comment: Thanks I am going to try this out.

Comment: I don't think we understood each other. If I get it right what you are showing in your code will allow me to translate Hardware and to include the variable in the translation. What I was saying is that I have variables which sometimes happend to be the word `Hardware` and sometimes `Matériel`. So I translate them like this `var | trans` .